# WTD: Method to Launch/Run Web app in a Window and minimize it to tray

Tags: webapps

I use a web To Do manager called todoist.com. Under Windows or MacOS, there is a desktop client, and there are extensions for Chrome and Firefox. There is no desktop client for Linux (I also couldn't run their app under Wine). My preference would be to be able to have ToDoist.com launch at startup in it's own window (without tabs or other normal browser functionality), apart from my regular browser, and act as a standalone application, and be minimizable to the tray. I'm using Franz which uses Electron to wrap around several messaging services, which behaves in the way I'm describing.

Is there a way to easily do this? BTW, I use Cinnamon desktop.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Chrome and Chromium, Google has hidden/changed the "save application shortcut" capability. I discovered that one can invoke the kabob menu on the right, and select more tools and then use "Add to Desktop," which prompts you whether you want to "Open as Window." This places a shortcut on your desktop, but also within ~/.local/share/applications with your intended target (I deleted the one on the desktop). I was able to then add this to my start up applications. I then remembered I could use gDevilspie (https://launchpad.net/gdevilspie) to get it to start minimized. Still would like two further tweaks: 1) how to launch this at a certain window size (although it seems to remember the last size) 2) how to get it to go into the tray